# Apple Mach - O - Linker errors

Tags: xcode, ios6

when i try to add other linker flags i.e. -lsqlite3.0 -ObjC i'm encountering the following error:

> **"_SecRandomCopyBytes", referenced from: "_kSecRandomDefault", referenced from: clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1
>   (use -v to see invocation)**

I was trying to add these flags in order to use Facebook SDK.

Comment: You forgot to add Security.framework like the facebook docs would tell you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select the project in the *Project Navigator*

Select the Target and then *Build Phases*

Add `Security.framework` in the *Link Binary With Libraries* list:

[image]